# What is the complexity of this sorting algorithm?

Tags: c++, sorting, find, complexity-theory

```
template<class T> void sSort(T *A, int first, int last) 
{
    if(A[first]>A[last])
        swap(A[first],A[last]);

    if(first+1>=last)
    return;
    double  k = floor((last-first+1)/3);


    sSort(A,first,last-k);
    sSort(A,first+k,last);
    sSort(A,first,last-k);
}
```

I perfectly understood the mergeSort, bubbleSort complexities but i'm so confused in this one. What is the complexity for this algorithm. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You could just try running it on a few arrays of different sizes and see how the time compares to the array size...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the [Stooge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort).  It's an algorithm constructed to show that amateurs really shouldn't implement their own algorithms without properly analyzing them first.  Its running time is approximately O(n^3).

Comment: Thank you, this link help me to reach further documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard to do the calc.

- Every time this algorithm do 3 calls to itself splitting into 3 (equal) part the portion of the input of the current step. **Note**: The first call and the third are the same.
- The local complexity is just a O(1) (which means constant) since it will do just a swap, an if and the calculation of k

Comment: I am rusty on this kind of thing, but I think it's a bit more involved as the three recursive calls operate on overlapping value ranges.

Comment: I actually stuck with 3 calls, i can't calculate them, i'm going kinda crazy :)

Comment: actually algorithm works, but so slowly, you can try to run it :). there aren't any mistyping in the algorithm.